# foreach inside foreach iterating double time

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a code in which foreach inside another foreach.

```
$order_id = '1,1,8';
$order_no_first= 'F,SH,C';

$order_id1 = explode(",", $order_id);
$order_no_first1 = explode(',', $order_no_first);

foreach($order_id1 as $ord_id){
    foreach($order_no_first1 as $ord_no_first){
        if($ord_id != '') {
            $this->receipt->chageBagStatus($ord_id, $ord_no_first);
            $add = $this->receipt->addJobOrderNew($ord_id, $ord_no_first, $bag_no);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the above code iterates 3 times resulting 9 rows in mysql.

```
//Current Output

order_id    orderr_no_first
--------    ---------------
   8              C
   8              SH
   8              F
   1              C
   1              SH
   1              F
   1              C
   1              SH
   1              F
```

The above output is wrong. I want the output as below,

```
//Required Output

order_id    orderr_no_first
--------    ---------------
   8              C
   1              SH
   1              F
```

I know it's because am using nested foreach. but I don't know how to solve this issue. Is there any solution. Thankyou.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework?
We would have to see what kind of sql you are building in order to help you.

Comment: Of course you are getting that output. For each value in the 1st array, you are going through the 2nd array. 3 X 3 = 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use one foreach like this,

```
foreach($order_id1 as $key => $ord_id){
        if($ord_id != '') {
            $this->receipt->chageBagStatus($ord_id, $order_no_first1[$key]);
            $add = $this->receipt->addJobOrderNew($ord_id, $order_no_first1[$key], $bag_no);
        }
}
```

Comment: `order_no_first` field showing null. No data showing.

Comment: @JithinVarghese check if  the $ord_no_first1[$key] have value.

Comment: change `$ord_no_first1[$key]` to `$order_no_first1[$key]`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you

```
$order_id = '1,1,8';
$order_no_first= 'F,SH,C';

$order_id1 = explode(",", $order_id);
$order_no_first1 = explode(',', $order_no_first);

rsort($order_id1);
asort($order_no_first1);

$i = 0;
foreach($order_id1 as $ord_id){
    echo $ord_id." &nbsp;&nbsp;".$order_no_first1[$i]."<br/>";
    $i++;
}
```

`